# How do I format numeric string value to 2 decimal places in Crystal Reports 2008?

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, data-manipulation, crystal-reports-2008

I am having trouble formatting field DetUnitPrice which is a string value to 2 decimal places. It is currently showing 4 decimal places and I need it to display 2 decimal places. I am trying to do this using Crystal Reports 2008. Can someone help?

Thanks

Dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's actually a string value you need to convert to a number:

```
CDbl("102.1234")
```

You can then set the format to have 2 decimal places.

If you want it to stay as text you can convert back to text:

```
CStr(CDbl("102.1234"), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you convert a number to text using the totext() function and handle the decimals.

totext({number_field}, 3)
112,158
Totext({EnforcmentOrdersTemplate.TotalPaid},3)

Answer (score 0):

The ToText() function accepts arguments that control number of decimals and thousand separator.  In the solution below, I don't specify the thousand separator argument, so it would be set to the default:

```
ToText(Val({DetUnitPrice}), 2)
```